# Which AWS RDS instance to upgrade given following usage pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have been using t2.medium RDS instance, which is experiencing regular exhaustion of CPU-Credit-balance. Following is the graph of CPU-Credit-balance for an interval of 6 weeks

[image]

Since next available instance i.e. t2.large offers same vCPU and ECU, does it provide any improvement in terms of processing capabilities (like increased CPU credits). What is the best course of action I could take in this scenario in terms of RDS instance and other measures(apart from optimizing queries which I will do but I need quick solution so that users don't suffer slow speed)

Comment: Move to a different instance class. The 't2' series instances are governed by CPU Credits. Refer this document: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/. Try the m3 series

Answer (score 1):

It's not just about CPU Credits which should be considered but also CPU Utilisation, Memory Utilisation, Queue Depth etc... Looks like you are using CPU Intensive queries.. Credit going down to zero looks like a serious concern should should be resolved.

With t2 instances; you do NOT get 100% of them.

As recommended by Krishna; I agree that you should try moving to m4.large instead of t4.large.